# How to download and unzip file via pipelines in gulp?

Tags: gulp, unzip

I'm trying to download and unpack zip archive in gulp by using [gulp-decompress](https://github.com/kevva/gulp-decompress). But get an error. My gulp task looks like the following:

```
var request = require('request');
var decompress = require('gulp-decompress');

gulp.task('unzip', function () {
   request('http://my-server-url/files/report.zip')
      .pipe(decompress())
      .pipe('./uploads')
});
```

After executing `gulp` I'm getting the following error:

```
node_modules\gulp-decompress\index.js:11
                if (file.isNull()) {
                         ^

TypeError: file.isNull is not a function
```

Comment: Are you sure you are getting into the pipe from the request() call?  You could check with gulp-tap for instance.

Comment: @Mark could you please provide an example ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I tried it with *request* and got the same error as you.  It probably has to be transformed into a readable or writeable stream (fs.) before continuing in the pipeline which I couldn't get to work without spending too much time.

So let me recommend [gulp-download](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-download) which is much simpler than *request*.

```
const gulp = require('gulp');
const download = require("gulp-download");
const decompress = require('gulp-decompress');

const url = 'http://my-server-url/files/report.zip';

gulp.task('unzip', function () {

  download(url)

   .pipe(decompress())
   .pipe(gulp.dest("unzipped"));
});
```

It's pretty simple.  I'm sure others could tell you how to get the module *request* to work if that is necessary.